# Excel export taking too much time

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, interop

I have 7 DataTables (of different number of rows, columns) in my asp.net page (C#). I am displaying the data on my page using GridViews. There is a requirement of exporting these dataTables to an excel file in such a way that I need the data of first 5 DataTables on first sheet including graphs thereof, data of 6th DataTable on 2nd sheet and data of 7th DataTable on 3rd sheet of the same excel file.
I implemented the solution using excel interop. The first sheet (having 5 datatables and graphs thereof) is loading fine. But second and third sheets are taking too much time (4000-5000 rows of data and 50 columns approx in each sheet) in loading.

Is there any way to load them fast?

I am using the following code:

```
Worksheet xlWorksheet2 = null;

//Create Excel Sheets

xlSheets = ExcelApp.Sheets;

xlWorksheet2 = (Worksheet)xlSheets.Add(xlSheets[2], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

xlWorksheet2.Name = "Dump-1";

table = Dump1();
for (int j = 1; j < table.Columns.Count + 1; j++)
{
    ExcelApp.Cells[1, j] = table.Columns[j - 1].ColumnName;
}

// Storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
for (k = 0; k < table.Rows.Count; k++)
{
    for (int l = 0; l < table.Columns.Count; l++)
    {
        ExcelApp.Cells[k + 2, l + 1] = table.Rows[k].ItemArray[l].ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: In VBA you can use Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual and Application.ScreenUpdating = False to speed up such things. Since you use the excel interop, you can also do this in C# too.

Comment: Its been some time that I worked on this. What you can do is to take the content of the table in form of an array and writing that array to excel. Let's say, you get an 2D array of 5 elements, you could do  ExcelApp.Cells("A1:A5").Value = myArray. This works in vba and am sure can work in c#.

Comment: I used ExcelApp.Cells["A1:E5"] = myArray; , but it is giving error as "The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"

Comment: A1:E5? I don't know what would happen with that instead of A1:A5

Comment: I resolved the issue...

I used 

object[,] arr = new object[dt.Rows.Count + 1, dt.Columns.Count];

Then I filled the above array
and then

Range c1 = (Range)xlWorksheet2.Cells[1, 1];
            Range c2 = (Range)xlWorksheet2.Cells[dt.Rows.Count + 1, dt.Columns.Count];
            Range range = xlWorksheet2.get_Range(c1, c2);

            range.Value = arr;